# How to define *object keys* using AngularJS models?

Tags: angularjs

I like to build a quick tool to define a "[JSON-schema](http://json-schema.org/)" which looks like this:

```
{
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
          "myFirstProperty": {
              "type": "integer"
          }
      },
      "title": "MySchema",
      "description": "some description"
    }
```

> See the *preview* here: http://jsfiddle.net/franquis/djRFN/4/embedded/result/
>
> See the *code* here: http://jsfiddle.net/franquis/djRFN/4/

Using a simple form, I can define the "*name*", "*description*" using the "**ng-model**" attributes, but when it comes to the "*properties*" definition of my schema, I have some troubles :)

**What I did is:**

1. First created a "**$scope.newProperties**" array, which store the properties I like to add to my schema "**$scope.schema**"
2. Added a listener on this array in order to add new properties to my "**$scope.schema.properties**"

**My issues:**

When I created a new property, while I typing the name of the new key (ie *hostname*), it creates a lot of new properies... 
See below:

```
{
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
         "h": {},
         "ho": {},
         "hos": {},
         "host": {},
         "hostn": {},
         "hostna": {},
         "hostnam": {},
         "hostname": {
            "type": "integer"
         }
      },
      "title": "MySchema",
      "description": "some description"
    }
```

I know this behavior is caused by the "**$watch("myva",function(a,b){},true);**" function, but what else can I try to succeed?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: But why do you need `newProperties`? Why not directly bind to `$scope.schema.properties` and edit them? In case if contain some other properties (like default set) you can have default set and filter properties by not been in that default set. But in general I think it is much easier to bind to resulting model.

Comment: I don't think I can bind an input to the **attribute name** of an object, right? If I'm wrong, do you have any example please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reset the `$scope.schema.properties` before iterating through the items:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){return $scope.newProperties;},function(items,b){
    $scope.newSchema.properties = {};
    angular.forEach(items, function(obj){
        if(angular.isDefined(obj.key)) {
            var key = obj.key, type = obj.type, name = obj.name;
            $scope.newSchema.properties[key] = {
                "name": name,
                "type": type
            };
        }
    });
},true);
```

It's the best way to keep the `$scope.schema` ordered and synced with the `$scope.newProperties`